# Identifying boundary of solid torus with itself by swapping coordinates

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Probably the following question is very elementary, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Let $T$ be the solid 2-torus and let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $T$ generated by the relation $\{(\alpha,\beta) \sim (\beta,\alpha) \mid \alpha, \beta \in S^1\}$ on the boundary $\partial T=S^1\times S^1$. What kind of 3-fold is $T/{\sim}$?

I believe that it is $S^3$, but I can't prove it.

**EDIT:** My idea is the following: Take two copies of the 3-ball $B$. Represent $T=B\coprod B/{\sim}$ by identifying half of their respective boundaries (I'm not sure how exactly, maybe opposite quadrants..). Then the quotient $T/{\sim}$ should be given by identifying the other half of the boundaries, but it is known that this gives $S^3$. Can this work?

**EDIT:** This question has been answered here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412288/quotient-of-solid-torus-by-swapping-coordinates-on-boundary

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does this quotient space comes into your mind? I mean, from where does this question come?

Comment: There is a cohomology theory for abelian groups by Eilenberg/MacLane which takes into account not just associativity but also commutativity. I wanted to find the geometrical counterparts of the generators of this complex. In particular, in addition to $[a,b,c] \in C_3(G)$ (3-simplex with vertices identified) we have a new generator $[a|b] \in C_3(G)$ corresponding to the solid torus with $\partial[a|b]=[a,b]-[b,a]$. In particular, $[a|a]$ is a cycle and this led me to the conjecture that the above quotient is $S^3$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're familiar with the construction of compact surfaces by glueing edges of a square. The torus $T$ can be obtain from Fig. $1$ below by glueing edges of the same color (red, blue) with respect to given direction. Under relation $\sim$, every point is identified with its reflection over the diagonal (the dashed line). So the quotient space we want is given by Fig. $2$, here we glue the colored edges together.
[image]
It's easy to see that Fig. $2$ can be obtained from Fig. $3$ by deform the bottom edge into a point. To get the quotient spaces of Fig. 2, one can change the order of taking quotient; that is, to find the quotient space of Fig. 3 first, after that deform the image of the bottom edge (under the quotient map) into a point. But the quotient space $X$ corresponds to Fig. $3$ is just the Mobius strip. The black edges on the top and bottom of the square is joined to become $X$'s boundary, which is $S^1$. Moreover, two pairs of opposite vertices are identified; they become $2$ separated points $A$ and $B$ on $X$'s boundary and divide  the boundary into $2$ half-circles (each of them is the image of a black edge in the quotient). Hence the deformation of the bottom edge still make $X$ a Mobius strip, but with $A$ and $B$ identified. Therefore, $\partial T/{\sim}$ (**edited** $T\to \partial T$) is homeomorphic to a Mobius strip.

Comment: Thx for this nice answer! However, I don't quite believe what you are saying. Up to Fig. 2 everything is fine and also deforming the lower right vertex into an edge is cool. But then after identifying red and blue edge, we need to identify half of the boundary of that moebius band and not just two points, right? I don't think that it's the same result, but maybe I'm wrong..

Comment: I will think about this more carefully and edit the answer. If there are some better answers after me, feel free to accept them. However, what make thing obscure here is that I implicitly use the following property: Instead of deforming Fig. 3 into Fig. 2 then taking quotient out of Fig. 2, I take the quotient spaces of Fig. 3 first and deform it after. The question is: how can these processes commute? Can we change the order of the quotient? I will figure it out somehow...

Comment: I was edited the answer. Hope that it's clear now.

Comment: @BipolarMinds: I believe that in the question as stated, $T$ is the **solid** torus, which would mean $D^2 \times S^1$, and $S^1 \times S^1$ is not $T$ itself but instead just the boundary $\partial T$. Is this correct?

Comment: @LeeMosher thats correct!

Comment: @withoutfeather As a quotient of a compact space, $T/\sim$ should again be compact

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. I will fix this one more time. Again, feel free to accept other answers if there are some. Also you can answer your question yourself!

Comment: Thank you! I would if I could ;)